# SQL Server : count symbols in game draws

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

My question is related to creating a new column in database which counts the number of times a symbol of this game called Totobola (symbols 1, X, 2)

Right now I have the following code where I have one table called Chaves with 2 rows which are the 2 actual 2016 draws of this game.

I want to add 3 columns (total1-counts number of 1's, totalx-counts number of x's, total2-counts number of 2's in each of the 2 draws):

```
CREATE DATABASE chaves_totobola;

CREATE table Chaves
(
    Num_Conc Int identity(1,1) primary key,
    datasort date,
    s1 char(1),
    s2 char(1),
    s3 char(1),
    s4 char(1),
    s5 char(1),
    s6 char(1),
    s7 char(1),
    s8 char(1),
    s9 char(1),
    s10 char(1),
    s11 char(1),
    s12 char(1),
    s13 char(1),
    s14 varchar(5),
    jackpot bit,
    premio money
);

INSERT INTO Chaves (datasort, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, jackpot, premio)
VALUES ('2016-01-03','2','X','X','X','1','2','2','X','1','2','X','X','2','M : 0','1','0'),
       ('2016-01-10','X','2','1','X','1','X','1','1','1','1','1','2','X','M : M','1','0');
```

Can you please help?

Comment: you got 3 answers... wanna accept one of them?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to concat all 13 columns (matches?) And then compare length of 1- the original string and 2- the string with substitute (or replace) (concat(s1,s2....),'X','') and again for the '1's and '2's so:`select *, length(concat(s1,s2...s13)) - length(replace(concat(s1,s2...s13),'1','')) as 'ones' (and again for 'x' and '2's) from tablename`

```
  select *,
concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13) as 'full_games_string',
length(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13))-length(replace(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13),'X','')) as 'Xs', 
length(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13))-length(replace(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13),'1','')) as '1s',
length(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13))-length(replace(concat(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13),'2','')) as '2s'

from Chaves
```

no need for double queries :)

[image]

Comment: You can also consider using a single string for the marches (no commas) which would make the concat part unneeded and you could just compare lengths

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT Count(v) 
        FROM   (VALUES (s1),(s2),(s3),(s4),...) AS value(v) 
        WHERE  v IN ( '2', '1', 'X' )) AS TOTAL_COUNT 
FROM   chaves
```

To get the individual count use this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                (SELECT Count(v) 
                 FROM   (VALUES (s1),(s2),(s3),(s4),..) AS value(v) 
                 WHERE  v = '1') AS count_1, 
                (SELECT Count(v) 
                 FROM   (VALUES (s1),(s2),(s3),(s4),..) AS value(v) 
                 WHERE  v = 'x') AS count_x, 
                (SELECT Count(v) 
                 FROM   (VALUES (s1),(s2),(s3),(s4),..) AS value(v) 
                 WHERE  v = '2') AS count_2 
         FROM   chaves) 
SELECT count_1 + count_x + count_2 AS TOTAL_COUNT 
FROM   cte;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaf8d/5)

Answer (score 0):

Your table is laid out like the result of a pivot query, and it will be MUCH easier to analyse that data if it is "unpivoted" first.

```
  SELECT   Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio, Symbol, SymValue
  FROM Chaves
      UNPIVOT (
             SymValue
             FOR [Symbol] IN ([s1], [s2], [s3], [s4], [s5], [s6], [s7], [s8], [s9], [s10], [s11], [s12], [s13])
              ) AS UPIV
```

The "unpivoted" rows look like this:

```
| Num_Conc |   datasort | jackpot | premio | Symbol | SymValue |
|----------|------------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |     s1 |        2 |
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |     s2 |        X |
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |     s3 |        X |
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |     s4 |        X |
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |     s5 |        1 |
```

Once the data is in this form it is a trivial task to count them using a GROUP BY clause and the COUNT() function.

```
SELECT
       Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = '1' then 1 end) as [total1-counts]
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = 'X' then 1 end) as [totalx-counts]
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = '2' then 1 end) as [total2-counts]
FROM (
      SELECT   Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio, Symbol, SymValue
      FROM Chaves
          UNPIVOT (
                 SymValue
                 FOR [Symbol] IN ([s1], [s2], [s3], [s4], [s5], [s6], [s7], [s8], [s9], [s10], [s11], [s12], [s13])
                  ) AS UPIV
      ) AS U
GROUP BY
     Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio
;
```

and the result is:

```
| Num_Conc |   datasort | jackpot | premio | total1-counts | totalx-counts | total2-counts |
|----------|------------|---------|--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|        1 | 2016-01-03 |    true |      0 |             2 |             6 |             5 |
|        2 | 2016-01-10 |    true |      0 |             7 |             4 |             2 |
```

There is an alternative syntax, using CROSS APPLY, instead of UNPIVOT, that produces the same result as above:

```
SELECT
       Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = '1' then 1 end) as [total1-counts]
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = 'X' then 1 end) as [totalx-counts]
     ,  count(case when U.SymValue = '2' then 1 end) as [total2-counts]
FROM Chaves
CROSS APPLY (
        values 
          ('s1' ,s1 )
        , ('s2' ,s2 )
        , ('s3' ,s3 )
        , ('s4' ,s4 )
        , ('s5' ,s5 )
        , ('s6' ,s6 )
        , ('s7' ,s7 )
        , ('s8' ,s8 )
        , ('s9' ,s9 )
        , ('s10' ,s10 )
        , ('s11' ,s11 )
        , ('s12' ,s12 )
        , ('s13' ,s13 )
        , ('s14' ,s14 )
        ) as U (symname,symvalue)
GROUP BY
     Num_Conc, datasort, jackpot, premio
;
```

You will probably find many circumstances where the pivoted table design complicates your analysis of the data so using an unpivot approach to normalize the data first may be something you will need to do often. If this is true note that the `CROSS APPLY` allows inclusion of [s14] into the "unpivotted" rows, but the `UNPIVOT operator` approach (top query) does NOT easily cater for this because [s14] is varchar(5) while the other columns are char(1) so type conversions would required. This make using CROSS APPLY simpler if you need [s14] "unpivoted".